# Name for this probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was wondering if the probability density function $1/\pi(1+x^2)$ has an agreed-upon name.

Comment: called Cauchy density

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Cauchy distribution you can see the following link 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution